# Change shape of WPF button without changing other styles

Tags: .net, wpf

I would like to change the shape of a WPF button from the default round rectangle to another shape (say, an arrow), but I want to keep the rest of the styling -- fill color, border color, hover states, etc. I want the button to have the same styles as all the other regular buttons (which I believe depends on the version of Windows, system theme colors, etc. so it's not like I can recreate the button style from scratch and hard code the right colors).

Is there some way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of the [default Button Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx), and simply change the default panel to your own custom shape.

In the case of the button, it looks like you need to replace the `Border` with something like a `Path` defining an Arrow.

Since a `Path` doesn't have content, you'll probably have to put both the shape and the content in another panel which allows objects to overlap, such as a Grid.

So your end result will look something like this

```
<Grid>
    <Path />
    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

instead of the default

```
<Button>
    <ContentPresenter />
</Button>
```

Comment: How do I get the "default button template"? The MSDN article you link to has a *sample* template, but it's not the default one.

Comment: @HenryJackson I think it is the default one other than the colors. By default it pulls colors from `SystemColors`. Another alternative is to make a copy of the template in Expression Blend.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to subclass the normal button control.  You can then customize the subclassed button with a custom shape, but all other properties would be inherited.  This would allow you to change the shape for your button and nothing else.

Here's a good resource for creating a custom button if you have Blend:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613598.aspx

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to override just the boundary? The MSDN article shows how to create a theme from scratch in Blend, which isn't quite what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inherit the default system colours/styles for a `Button` you can use `TemplateBinding`s within the button `Template`.  For example, if you wanted to create a custom-shaped button that had the same background colour as the system one, you could use the below:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <!-- circle to have inherited colour -->
                <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="50" Width="50" />
                <ContentPresenter />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

The `Ellipse` will then inherit the background colour from the `Button`, however it is set.

Comment: This does get the background color right, but it's otherwise just a circle. There's no border, no hover or click states, no gradient gloss over the content. I'm trying to avoid making a whole button from scratch.