# How to use a polygon as a button in Surface?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to make my first app for Microsoft Surface. I need to use a polygon as a button. But I really don't know, how to start. I know how to use the regular button, hadle its its action etc. But what i have to do when i need trianglular (or different) button?

Could you give me a clue?

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF you can use styles and/or templates to define how a button looks like. So you can use a path to create your shape.

There's another question answering this respective a similar question: [Change shape of WPF button without changing other styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118861/change-shape-of-wpf-button-without-changing-other-styles)